# I want to make my div float left behind the previous div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="ans_chk">
  <input id="Answer_Response[3]" name="Answer.Response[3]" value="False" type="checkbox"
</div>
<div style="font-weight: bold;" class="ans_opt" id="ans_opt_3">D)</div>
<div style="font-weight: 600;" class="ans_txt" id="ans_txt_3">xxx</div>
<div class="ans_exp" id="ans_exp_3"> - If message.</div>
```

But it's a problem because ans_exp_3 always goes to a new line if there are more than a certain number of characters.

Is there a way that I can make ans_exp_3 just tag along behind the text of ans_txt_3 ?

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about CSS to stop it wrapping.

```
.ans_exp {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Or if you want the `ans_exp_3` to be rendered next to the `#ans_txt_3` you could float the `#and_txt_3` with:

```
.ans_txt {
    float:left;
}
```

See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aFNr8/1/).